# Creating date field with only month and year

Tags: 8, forms

We are using the Form API in a custom module (and not an entity field), how can we easily set the date widget for just year and month data entry?

I've tried adding a `#date_format` attribute but no change:

```
$form['date_needed'] = array(
  '#type' => 'date',
  '#title' => $this->t('Date Needed'),
  '#date_date_format' => 'Y/m',
);
```

I have also tried  `'#date_date_format' => 'd/m/Y'` but the date widget still appears asking for `YYYY-mm-dd`.

Looking at the source code for `core/Render/Element/Date.php` and stepping though the code, I can see it's picking up this setting.

The drupal.org doc page has a comment that indicate this should work: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21Element%21Date.php/class/Date/8.2.x

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

We can make this in a hook_form_alter.

```
$form['DATE_FIELD_MACHINE_NAME']['widget'][0]['value']['#date_date_element'] = 'month';
$form['DATE_FIELD_MACHINE_NAME']['widget'][0]['value']['#date_date_format'] = 'Y-m';
```

However, there is still a problem of this way:  instead of first day of the month, current day will be saved. I cannot figure out how to solve.

Comment: You may want to expand and write about why you think this would help based on the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work, just tested it in my own form class:

```
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    return [
      'date_needed' => [
        '#type' => 'date',
        '#title' => $this->t('Date Needed'),
        '#date_date_format' => 'm/Y',
      ],
}
```

My browser changes the displayed date value as provided in the value of `#date_date_format`. In the rendered HTML I also see the `data-drupal-attribute`:

```
<input data-drupal-selector="edit-date-needed" data-drupal-date-format="m-Y" id="edit-date-needed" name="date_needed" value="" class="form-date hasDatepicker" type="date">
```

I am testing with Drupal 8.3.4. Perhaps your core version is lower?

Answer (score 0):

Add attribute type "month", this will render as

```
<input type="month">
```

Of course the modern day Internet Explorer (Safari) doesn't support this. Well it doesn't support date pickers out of the box anyway so... Actually not supported by Firefox either yet :(

```
  $form['date_to'] = [
    '#title' => 'To',
    '#type' => 'date',
    '#date_date_format' => 'm/Y',
    '#attributes' => ['type'=> 'month']
  ];
```

Funny how mozilla documentation explains it but doesn't support it its browser: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/month